# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*' at line 5

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Whats wrong with my code? The specific error message is:

> Error querying database You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*' at line 5

My code is:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];

$query = mysql_query("
    SELECT timein, timeout 
    FROM studentInfo
    WHERE name = '$name' 
    ORDER BY time DESC
    LIMIT *
    ")
    or die("Error querying database ".mysql_error());
while($minutes = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
  echo "timein: ".$minutes['timein']."<br />";
  echo "timeout: ".$minutes['timeout']."<br />";
  }
  }
```

Comment: After `Limit` put some whole number not a `*` wild card.

Comment: What do you think `LIMIT *` is supposed to do? It ain't a syntax MySQL is familiar with...

Comment: This code has a SQL injection vulnerability in it.

Comment: Also: obligatory: you are vulnerable for SQL injection, fix that. ASAP. Seriously.

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong:

```
LIMIT *
```

After `Limit` put some whole number not a `*` wild card.

As per [*documentation*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html):

> The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be nonnegative integer constants (except when using prepared statements).

With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of rows to return. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15
```

To retrieve all rows from a certain offset up to the end of the result set, you can use some large number for the second parameter. This statement retrieves all rows from the 96th row to the last:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 95,18446744073709551615;
```

With one argument, the value specifies the number of rows to return from the beginning of the result set:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5;     # Retrieve first 5 rows
```

In other words, LIMIT row_count is equivalent to LIMIT 0, row_count.

Answer (score 0):

limit should be a value( nonnegative integer ) not `*`

```
$query = mysql_query("
    SELECT timein, timeout 
    FROM studentInfo
    WHERE name = '$name' 
    ORDER BY time DESC
    LIMIT 100
    ")
    or die("Error querying database ".mysql_error());
```

it will return first 100 rows.